# How to generate Paragraph in itext conditionally and add content to it

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I have got some content in ArrayList , from which i want to generate a PDF file

The Content in the ArrayList goes this way

```
ArrayList<String> my_list = new ArrayList<String>();

my_list.add("Today Date");
my_list.add("Some Content1");
my_list.add("*****");
my_list.add("Some Content2");
my_list.add("Some Content3");
my_list.add("Some Content4");
my_list.add("*****");
my_list.add("Some Content5");
my_list.add("Some Content6");
my_list.add("Some Content7");
my_list.add("*****");
my_list.add("Some Content8");
```

My requirement is that i want to generate a new Paragraph after every ******

I started this way as shown but couldn't proceed further on this

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

        ArrayList<String> my_list = new ArrayList<String>();

        my_list.add("Today Date");
        my_list.add("Some Content1");
        my_list.add("*****");
        my_list.add("Some Content2");
        my_list.add("Some Content3");
        my_list.add("Some Content4");
        my_list.add("*****");
        my_list.add("Some Content5");
        my_list.add("Some Content6");
        my_list.add("Some Content7");
        my_list.add("*****");
        my_list.add("Some Content8");
        // Writing Content to PDF Starts here 

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document,new FileOutputStream("D:\\Test\\Paragraph2.pdf"));
        document.open();


    /*  for(int i=0;i<my_list.size();i++)
        {
            String linedata = my_list.get(i);
            if(linedata.contains("********"))
            {
                document.add(new Paragraph("A Hello World PDF document."));
            }
        }*/
         document.close(); 

    }
}
```

Could you please tell me how to approach this ??

Comment: *"My requirement is that i want to generate a new Paragraph after every ******"*, But you are checking for `linedata.contains("********")`. Why?

Comment: shouldn't your `if` condition be `if(linedata.equals("*****"))`?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking `"********"` while your separator actually is `"*****"`.

Therefore try:

```
for(String s : my_list) {
    if(s.equals("*****")) {
        document.add(new Paragraph("A Hello World PDF document."));
    }
    // ...
}
```